# RSpec test failing for routes that accept id param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I'm trying to test the ArticlesController in my Rails applications. All of the routes that do not accept params are passing. But all of the routes that expect an id param are failing.

#### Failures:

```
  1) ArticlesController should find article by id
     Failure/Error: get :info, id: @article[:id]
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"info", :controller=>"articles", :id=>"60"}
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ArticlesController should export folder
     Failure/Error: get :export_folder, id: @article[:id]
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"export_folder", :controller=>"articles", :id=>"60"}
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) ArticlesController should export an article by id
     Failure/Error: get :export, id: @article[:id]
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"export", :controller=>"articles", :id=>"60"}
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
get '/articles/list' => 'articles#list', defaults: { format: :html }
  get '/articles/trendlist' => 'articles#trendlist', defaults: { format: :html }
  get '/articles/show/:id' => 'articles#show', defaults: { format: :html }, as: :show_article
  get '/articles/index'
  get '/articles/info/:id' => 'articles#info', as: :article_info
  get '/articles/export/:id' => 'articles#export', as: :export_article
  get '/articles/view/:id' => 'articles#view'
  get '/articles/favorite/:id' => 'articles#favorite'
  get '/articles/trending' => 'articles#trending', defaults: { format: :json }
  get '/articles/deleted' => 'articles#deleted', defaults: { format: :json }
  get '/articles/csv/:id' => 'articles#csv'
  get '/articles/export_folder/:id' => 'articles#export_folder', as: :export_folder
```

#### spec/controllers/articles_controller.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ArticlesController do
  before(:all) do
    Article.destroy_all
    Comfy::Cms::Layout.destroy_all
    Comfy::Cms::Site.destroy_all
    site = FactoryGirl.create(:cms_site)
    layout = FactoryGirl.create(:cms_layout, site_id: site[:id])
    @article = FactoryGirl.create(:cms_page, layout_id: layout[:id], site_id: site[:id])
  end

  it 'should index articles' do
    get :index
    expect(response.response_code).to eq(200)
    expect(response.headers).to include( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
  end

  its 'should list articles' do
    get :list
    expect(response.response_code).to eq(200)
    expect(response.headers).to include( 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
  end

  it 'should find article by id' do
    get :info, id: @article[:id]
    expect(response.response_code).to eq(200)
    expect(response.headers).to include( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
  end

  it 'should list deleted articles' do
    get :deleted
    expect(response.response_code).to eq(200)
    expect(response.headers).to include( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
  end

  it 'should list trending articles' do
    get :trending
    expect(response.response_code).to eq(200)
    expect(response.headers).to include( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
  end

  it 'should update trending articles' do
    get :trendlist
    expect(response.response_code).to eq(200)
    expect(response.headers).to include( 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
  end

  it 'should export an article by id' do
    get :export, id: @article[:id]
    expect(response.response_code).to eq(200)
    expect(response.headers).to include( 'Content-Type' => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8')
  end

  it 'should export folder' do
    get :export_folder, id: @article[:id]
    response.response_code.should eq(200)
    expect(response.headers).to include( 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
  end
end
```

#### rake routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                               Controller#Action
                                        tags GET    /tags(.:format)                                                           tags#index
                               articles_list GET    /articles/list(.:format)                                                  articles#list
                          articles_trendlist GET    /articles/trendlist(.:format)                                             articles#trendlist
                                    articles GET    /articles/show/:id(.:format)                                              articles/articles#show
                              articles_index GET    /articles/index(.:format)                                                 articles#index
                                             GET    /articles/info/:id(.:format)                                              articles/articles#info
                                             GET    /articles/export/:id(.:format)                                            articles/articles#export
                                             GET    /articles/view/:id(.:format)                                              articles/articles#view
                                             GET    /articles/favorite/:id(.:format)                                          articles/articles#favorite
                           articles_trending GET    /articles/trending(.:format)                                              articles#trending
                            articles_deleted GET    /articles/deleted(.:format)                                               articles#deleted
                                             GET    /articles/csv/:id(.:format)                                               articles/articles#csv
                                             GET    /articles/export_folder/:id(.:format)                                     articles/articles#export_folder
```

#### app/controllers/articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  include ArticlesHelper

  before_action :set_default_response_format, except: [:pdf, :show, :list, :trendlist, :export_folder]

  def index
    @articles = SearchArticlesCommand.new(params).execute
  end

  def deleted
    @dlist = Article.deleted.map(&:article_id)
    render :ids, status: :ok
  end

  def info
    id = params[:id].to_i
    @article = Article.published.find_by(id: id)
  end

  def list
    @articles = Article.folder
    render 'articles/list'
  end

  def favorite
    ...
    render json: { result: true, is_liked: "#{is_liked}" }
  end

  def view
    ...
    render json: { result: true }
  end

  def trending
    load_trending_articles
  end

  def trendlist
    load_trending_articles
    render 'articles/trendlist'
  end

  def export
    id = params[:id].to_i
    @article = Article.published.find_by(id: id)

    render pdf: @article.label.gsub(/\s/, '_'),
           template: 'articles/export.pdf.erb',
           dispostion: 'attachment',
           locals: { paragraphs: @article.paragraphs, images: @article.images }
```

Comment: Add the contents of your `ArticlesController`. Specify the file path and name at the top as a comment.

Comment: Is your controller really in `spec/controllers/articles_controller.rb` and not `/app/controllers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not really what `namespace` is used for. You can read up more on it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing). Use `resources` instead and specify `member` for the one with `id`:

```
resources :articles, only: [] do
  collection do 
    get :list
    get :trendlist
    get :trending
    get :deleted
  end

  member do
    get :info
    get :export
    get :view
    get :favorite
    get :csv
    get :export_folder
  end
end

get 'articles/index', to: 'articles#index'
get 'articles/show/:id', to: 'articles#show'
```

Comment: I can't uses resources because the index view would be `articles/` instead of  `articles/index/` which is already being used by client that can't be changed.

Comment: Its actually the same case so it would look like `only: []` which feels wrong

Comment: What do you mean 'the same case'? Same case for the `show` action?

Comment: show needs to be access via `articles/show/:id` not `article/:id`

Comment: I will update the routes file to how it was before I took over this project.

Comment: Using this way the id precedes the action, `http://localhost:5000/articles/81/export`. But the client enters the id last, `http://localhost:5000/articles/export/81`

Comment: You update will lead me to reverting all the member routes to what I originally had which working in the browser but not rspec.

Comment: Actually moving all of the member functions now works.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the output of `rake routes` you can see that Rails is looking for `articles/articles#show` etc. `namespace` is for creating routes which live in a namespace (duh) such as `/admin/tools` which would root to `Admin::ToolsController`.

You can instead use `scope` which adds a url prefix but not the namespace or `resources`:

```
resources :articles, only: [:show, :index] do
  member do
    get 'info'
    get 'export' # Use /articles/1.format instead.
    get 'view' # Do you need this? Code smell!
    get 'favorite' # should be post - GET should never create or alter a resource.
    get 'csv' # remove - use /articles/1.csv instead
    get 'show' # /articles/show/3
  end
  collection do
    get 'trending'
    get 'deleted'
    get 'trendlist'
    get 'list' # Do you need this? Code smell!
    get 'index' # /articles/index
  end
end
```

I would also question why you actually need so many routes beyond the standard CRUD set.
Especially routes which are extremely in semantics like view and show and list and index.

I would use query parameters around a smaller set of routes as it reduces the amount of duplication on all levels.

```
/articles?filter=deleted => index
/articles?filter=trending
```

Rails also has a built in CSV mime type so you can do:

`/articles/5.csv`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.order(:name)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @article.to_csv }
    end
  end
end
```

Using `@article[:id]` vs `@article.id` does work but its unidiomatic and very slightly slower since rails has to go through the `[]` method just to find the getter method. Its not a huge deal in this case but not great when you are dealing with a large number of objects.

Comment: I already have clients in production changing the api(using filters) is not an option for me at this point

Comment: Well, too bad. But I would definitely consider it if you in the future move to a versioned API.

Comment: Updated answer with a `/articles/show/:id` route. I recommend that you [read the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) - its really trivial to customize the routes.

Comment: There are a lot of code smells but we can change it because the client would have to be updated.

Comment: Yeah I get that, I feel for you - it sucks to inherit projects from people who don't know what the f* they are doing. I would add the weird routes with `get '/articles/export/:id/'`  above resources and then try to move to a more sane versioned API when possible.